# Is chrome stalling the redirected request?

Tags: google-chrome, webserver, http-redirect, playframework-2.6

As part of email signup process, I send a url in an email. The client should click it, my server applications sends a `303` response redirecting the client to the home page and the browser should open the home page. But this isn't happening. I am unable to debug whether this is a browser issue or web-server issue.

in this pic, you could see that on clicking the url, a request `GET` is sent and `303` is received

[image]

Here, I don't see any request going out (I see request headers but I am not convinced that the request was sent). In the timing tab, it looks as if the request is stalled

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was the way I was redirecting. In of redirecting using absolute path `Redirect("http://localhost:9000/home")`, I wasn't using `http` i.e. `Redirect("localhost:9000/home")` which made the path relative. The initial request was `http://localhost:9000/ws/users/signup/` and the new request after redirect became `http://localhost:9000/ws/users/signup/localhost:9000/home` which probably messed up something in the browser.